# jQueryUI: How to drag onto droppable placeholders, replace an existing element, then shift existing dropped items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm working on an interface that requires me to do a drag and drop onto placeholders from one unordered list to another.  However, I need to be able to sort on the drop even if elements already exist.

The easiest way to explain this is we're looking to replace the existing element on drop, and push the other children down or up to the closest empty parent elements.

Here is [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hatfieldajoshua/LFLXG/) and a [fullscreen link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hatfieldajoshua/LFLXG/show/) for anyone

Thanks in advance!

JavaScript:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
    // start: function(ev, ui){ ui.helper.width($(this).width()); }
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept : ".draggable",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy : true,
    hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({position : 'relative', top: 'auto',left: 'auto'}).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<h1>jQuery Drag, Drop, &amp; Reorder</h1>

<div id="left" class="left">

    <h2>Drag from this side</h2>

    <ul>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">A</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">B</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">C</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">D</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">E</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">F</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">G</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">H</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">I</span></li>
        <li class="list-item"><span class="draggable">J</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div id="right" class="right">

    <h2>to this side</h2>

    <ul>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
        <li class="list-item droppable"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you find a use if you swap the positions of the two elements? If yes than you can have use of this [swappable](http://www.eslinstructor.net/demo/swappable/swappable_home.html) plugin